# vtysh: Symbol `config_list_cmd' has different size in shared object, consider re-linking

Tags: permissions, directory, libraries

when i use vtysh command its give me this error

vtysh: Symbol `config_list_cmd' has different size in shared object, consider re-linking

vtysh: Symbol `integrate_default' has different size in shared object, consider re-linking

Command node 41 doesn't exist, please check it

how can i solve this. kindly help me

Ubuntu 16.04
kernel 4.15.0